# How can I send E-Mail Notifications in node.js

Tags: node.js, email, npm

My query is simple, all of us receive many e-mail notifications and alerts every day and from various companies. I want to achieve exactly the same. I searched as much as I can, but I could only find the way to send the mail from my personal account (Gmail). But I want to use the company's account to send the mail.

If I use nodemailer, I need to use some smtp-host or some service (like Gmail), then I need to put some credentials (`auth`) to send.

But if I want to use the private company's account. How can I do it with that? I can't say `service: "myPrivateCompany"` and and assign properties to `auth`, it won't work, it works with Gmail, but it won't work with private company,

how can I make it work so the receiver knows which company/website or platform has sent e-mail?

I am a beginner as you know by now. Can someone also explain a bit about the `'service'` and `smptp-host` and `port`?.

Here's the picture of what I have tried.[image]

Comment: Please read [ask], in particular the part about not posting pictures of text.

Comment: "But if I want to use the private company's account" — Account with what service?

Comment: That is what I am asking, if anyone could define the "service" part. Like it works if I put "gmail" as a service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello here are my code I use for my company:

```
export const sendEmails = async () => {
  try {
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: "smtp.your server",
      port: server port,
      secure: false,
      auth: {
        user: "email to used to send",
        pass: "That email password",
      },
      tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
      },
    });

    let info = await transporter.sendMail({
      from: "Sender email",
      to: "email to send to,
      subject: header,
      html: "message",
    });
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error(e);
  }
};
```

The above is a function I use to send my email from my nodejs app.Try it am sure it will help

You can also pass in email,message and subject for easie

Comment: Thank you, but can you explain `host` and `port`, where does it come from?

Comment: If your working for a company, they must having an email server they use. say something like soandso.com, then the port is the port of access to that server.

Comment: They should give you the sender email too

Comment: If this works for you please mark it as a write answer so that others can benefit

Comment: Thank you, I'll accept your answer, for now, it does clear some of my queries. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

> That is what I am asking, if anyone could define the "service" part. Like it works if I put "gmail" as a service

That just reads some configuration options from [a JSON file distributed with Nodemailer](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/blob/fcb0d1f5918a89ca5e8ab880134fec07c4e92bc7/lib/well-known/services.json).

e.g. the Gmail part looks like:

> ```
> "Gmail": {
>     "aliases": ["Google Mail"],
>     "domains": ["gmail.com", "googlemail.com"],
>     "host": "smtp.gmail.com",
>     "port": 465,
>     "secure": true
> },
> ```

It's only useful if you're using a large third-party email service which Nodemailer has the data for. Otherwise you need to supply the configuration for your mail server explicitly instead of using the `service` shorthand.

e.g. as per [the documentation](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/):

> ```
> nodemailer.createTransport({
>   host: "smtp.example.com",
>   port: 587,
>   secure: false, // upgrade later with STARTTLS
>   auth: {
>     user: "username",
>     pass: "password",
>   },
> });
> ```